# Lua script in Splash - direct file download by button click

Tags: lua, splash-js-render

How to directly download and save a file by button click using Splash Lua?

[Example page](https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals) and the download button:
[image: screenshot of the website]

Conditions:

- The download URL is generated dynamically upon button click
- Clicking the button will open a "Save As" prompt window to save the Excel file
- I am using a Splash docker service on `localhost:8050`. I write Lua script directly on the page.

I have searched the [official docs about binary download](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-binary-data.html#binary-objects), but the closest things I have managed to find were `html:jpeg`, `html:png` and `response.body`, which didn't quite seem to hit the mark. I also found no explicit examples or tutorials on Youtube.

Note: **Please do not give workarounds** such as using Selenium. I am only interested in how to do it with Lua.

Comment: I have checked with lua and after clicking the button and waiting some while I get `Failed Loading Page`, so making this click will redirect the page to a download without a `Save As` prompt.